# Is there a react-native code for rewards points that give to a customer when he bought?

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react-native so I want to know if there any code or tutorial that help me how I can give the rewards points to customers depends on purchase amount? and what I need? and how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too vague. Please reformulate the question and give an example of what you have already tried and what you did not succeed.

Comment: hey there , can you describe the problem more so that we can know exactly what you want? reward is a very generic term. what kind of app are you making?